# Why is my program not showing background color change after an interval?

Tags: java, colors

I have been trying for hours to figure out my mistake in a simple program in java. I wish to display the change in backgroundcolor after 200 ms so I wrote this program but it's not showing correct output.

It's a long program ahead thanks in advance for reading.

```
public class bgColor extends Applet implements Runnable
{
     Thread timer=null;
     int c,flag;
  public void init()
  {
    c=0;
    setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));  
  }
  public void start()
  {
     if(timer==null)
    {
     timer=new Thread(this);
     timer.start();
    }
  }
 public void paint(Graphics g)
 {
  switch(c)
  {
  case 0:setBackground(Color.white);
         break;
  case 1:setBackground(Color.blue);
         break;
  case 2:setBackground(Color.green);
         break;
  case 3:setBackground(Color.red);
         break;
  }
 if(c==4)
 {
  flag=0;
 }
 else if(c==0)
 {
  flag=1;
 }
 if(flag==0)
 {
   c--;
 }
 else if(flag==1)
 {
   c++;
 }
}
public void stop()
{
   timer=null;
}
public void run()
{
   if(timer!=null)
   {
         repaint();
         c++;
   try
   {
         Thread.sleep(200);
   }
   catch(InterruptedException e){}
   }
         timer=null;
}
}
```

I basically set up a switch for changing background Color after certain intervals but it's showing only red Color throughout.

It would also be of enormous help if someone could suggest where I can read up how the program runs step by step like I think probably init(), then start() then run() then paint() then stop() but it's purely my guess. I need an authentic source.

Comment: declare `volatile int c; int flag;` so the two threads may share the fields. Otherwise a thread's change will not reach the other thread that then uses a stale value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing `c`?

The thread runs more often than `paint` since even if you call `repaint` a million times, it only paints at most once per frame. The sleep helps, but it only reduces the risk of a race condition instead of eliminating the issue.

You also have a race condition where `c` can go above 4 and flag will never toggle. Try using `c >= 4` and `c <= 0` instead to avoid this. Based on your description, this is probably your issue.

Comment: Printing C was the most helpful

Comment: Can I ask one more thing? Please could you tell me exactly what repaint() does here?  And also please mention the order of traversal(2nd part of my question)

Comment: `repaint()` simply requests that the window/component be repainted on the next frame. It will attempt to reuse the previous frame unless paint has been requested. It does not make sense to have a framerate higher than your monitor refresh rate so it doesn't try to. `paint(...)` method is then called by the graphics/event thread (usually named some variation on `awt-eventqueue-0`). You also shouldn't expect `paint` to only be called when using `repaint`. Other events like resizing the window will also trigger a paint event. Since two threads are involved, it is very prone to race conditions.